# Oracle SQL - group only by nearby same records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, grouping

I need to sum delay time in seconds for records that are same by value column. Problem is I need them only grouped by the same chunks and not all together. For example, for below data I would need sum of 3 records for value 3 and separately for 2 records further down, and not to sum records for value 4 as they are not together. Is there a way to do this?

```
ID     Value   Timestamp       Delay(s)
166549627   4   19-OCT-21 11:00:19  11.4
166549450   8   19-OCT-21 11:00:27  7.5
166549446   3   19-OCT-21 11:00:34  7.1
166549625   3   19-OCT-21 11:00:45  10.9
166549631   3   19-OCT-21 11:00:58  13.3
166550549   3   19-OCT-21 11:01:03  4.5
166549618   7   19-OCT-21 11:01:14  8.8
166549627   4   19-OCT-21 11:01:23  11.4
166550549   3   19-OCT-21 11:01:45  4.5
166550549   3   19-OCT-21 11:01:59  4.5
```

Comment: desired output ?

Comment: @Abra no, that is not what I want, I only want to lump together when same values are next to each other not everything together.

Comment: This is known as an Sql  gaps and islands problem. A lot of answers could be found.

Comment: Thank you Serg, I didn't know how to call this so wasn't able to find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use plsql for that purpose. Only SQL can suffice.
Below solution uses the **recursive common table expression** (CTE) technic to create sub groups according to value column and timestamp column.

```sql
with ranked_rows (ID, VALUE, TIMESTAMP, DELAY, RNB) as (
select ID, VALUE, TIMESTAMP, DELAY, row_number()over(order by TIMESTAMP) rnb
from YourTable
)
, cte (ID, VALUE, TIMESTAMP, DELAY, RNB, grp) as (
select ID, VALUE, TIMESTAMP, DELAY, RNB, 1 grp
from ranked_rows
where rnb = 1
union all
select t.ID, t.VALUE, t.TIMESTAMP, t.DELAY, t.RNB, case when c.VALUE = t.VALUE then c.grp else c.grp + 1 end
from ranked_rows t
join cte c on c.rnb + 1 = t.rnb
)
select VALUE, sum(DELAY) sum_consecutive_DELAY, min(TIMESTAMP) min_TIMESTAMP, max(TIMESTAMP) max_TIMESTAMP, count(*)nb_rows
from cte
group by VALUE, GRP
order by min_TIMESTAMP
;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0384f0bdf95426252daa5d4626382997)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PL/SQL you can loop over all records orderd by timestamp.

Just remember the last value und sum up if it is the same as the current value. If not, just save the sum somewehre else and continue.

You can also write this as a pipelined function to use a query to access the data.

```
declare
    l_sum      number := 0;
    l_last_val number;
begin
    for rec in (select * from your_table order by timestamp) loop
        if l_last_val = rec.value then
            l_sum := l_sum + rec.delay;
            continue;
        elsif l_last_val is not null then
            dbms_output.put_line('value: ' || l_last_val || ' sum: ' || l_sum); -- save last_val and sum
        end if;
            l_last_val := rec.val;
            l_sum      := rec.delay;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('value: ' || l_last_val || ' sum: ' || l_sum); -- save last_val and sum
end;
```

Comment: Would you be able to write an example? I'm not that good in loops in oracle, thank you

Comment: Stupid question, but how would you show output as a table instead of dbms_output?

Comment: dbms_output was only an example and is not intended to be used in production.
As mentioned before use a [pipelined function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm#CHDJEGHC)  instead.